# How to use a variable as a field name in mongodb-native findOne()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this data in mongodb:

```
{  
    "name": "Amey",
    "country": "India",
    "region": "Dhule,Maharashtra"
}
```

and I want to retrieve the data while passing a field name as a variable in query.

Following does not work:

```
var name = req.params.name;
var value = req.params.value;
collection.findOne({name: value}, function(err, item) {
    res.send(item);
});
```

How can I query mongodb keeping both field name and its value dynamic?

Comment: Just found this post. I think that this is really insecure. Don't you think that you should sanitize before using those values in a query?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You need to set the key of the query object dynamically:

```
var name = req.params.name;
var value = req.params.value;
var query = {};
query[name] = value;
collection.findOne(query, function (err, item) { ... });
```

When you do `{name: value}`, the key is the string `'name'` and not the value of the variable `name`.

Comment: What if you want to use operators such as $gt inside the query?

Comment: You replace `value` by your query like `{ $gt: 50 }`

Comment: How to pass regular express using above solution var query = {};
query[name] = value; ?

Comment: I succeed
var  query = {};
query['registrationNo'] = { "$regex": sCode, "$options": "m" } ;

Comment: @maxdec great answer! would you happen to take a look at this problem, similar to this but different scenario..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568967/mongodb-how-do-i-return-documents-with-field-value-as-field-key

Comment: @levelone someone was faster than me :)

Answer (score 74):

Just put the variable in []

```
var name=req.params.name;
var value = req.params.value;
collection.findOne({[name]:value}, function(err, item) {
res.send(item);
});
```

Comment: Your answer is much straight forward!

Comment: This doesn't work as a direct mongo query; you get an error back *E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token [*. I'm not sure how it can work in node.js?

Comment: I think the reason is that nodejs will do transformation when it interact with mongodb.

Comment: this work on native mongodb drive for nodejs ! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This worked in my much more abstract code for which the accepted answer made no sense (for the record, react not nodeJs).

Comment: @KiwenLau What do the [] brackets do? How does this magically work?

Comment: This is great in mongo cli for data evaluation. I could use it both for query and projection part of the find function; and just change the f value and repeat the command.

f = "field_name"
db.col.find({[f]: {$gt: ""}}, {[f]: 1})

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to clarify that if you're trying to make a query concerning a nested field only (not its value), like if you want to query the field "name" from this document:

```
{
    loc: [0, 3],
    unit: {
        name : "playername"
    }
}
```

this will work (as in my case - using update):

```
mdb.cords.updateOne(
    {_id: ObjectID(someid)}, 
    {$set: {[query]: newValue}}, 
    function (err, result) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Simply enclosing `[query]` in brackets tells mongodb that it's not literal, but rather a path.

Answer (score 5):

use like this if the object is nested.

An object is nested:-

```
var surname=req.params.surname;
var value = req.params.value;
var condition = `name.${surname}`
collection.findOne({[condition]:value}, function(err, item) {
res.send(item);
});
```