# Query with variables in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Query for a user that looks like this:

```
var getUser = function(query) {
  var q = query.q, by = query.by === 'id' ? '_id' : query.by;
  Account.findOne({by:q}).exec(function(error, result) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
    console.log('result: ' + result);
  });
}
getUser({by: 'id', q: '53mklmrt34klm'});
```

The result is:

```
error: null

result: null
```

Is there a way to achieve querying with variables both in the data AND the fieldname?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way in which you are defining you `JSON` `query param` for `Account.findOne` is not correct.

Instead of:

```
Account.findOne({by:q}).exec(function(error, result) {/* Your code here */});
```

Use:

```
var queryParam = {};
queryParam[by] = q;
Account.findOne(queryParam).exec(function(error, result) {/* Your code here */});
```

Comment: Thank you. I later found out that it was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039018/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-field-name-in-mongodb-native-findone