# find query resulting in empty when using parameters in the field for nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am trying to find users near a certain location and where the field1=No and field2=No (which is what cat is equal to (field2)) but when i try to run the query like this it returns no results

```
function (currentLoc, radius, cat, db, callback) {
    ...
    var query = db.collection('User').find({
        CurrentLoc: {
            $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [currentLoc, maxDistance] }
        }, 
        field1: "No",
        cat: "Yes"
    });
}
```

If I try and run the query with field2 instead of the parameter cat the query works and returns the result.  Not sure why it won't work with passing in the parameter as well

Comment: I'm a little confused. So your object looks like `{ field1: 'No', cat: 'yes' }` or `{  field1: 'No', field2: 'Yes' }`? I'm not sure what you mean by field2 is equal to cat.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is in the database there is {field1: 'No', field2: 'Yes'}.  In this function the cat parameter is getting passed in a string of field2.  Does that clarify it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling it to look for the property 'cat'. You need to manually set the query property. See [How to use a variable as a field name in mongodb-native findOne()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039018/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-field-name-in-mongodb-native-findone)

Comment: so I am trying to follow the example of the link but I am getting req in undefined.  Where is that suppose to be defined? Also same with params, is there a library i need to import?

Comment: Sorry was on mobile earlier so gave a quick reply. The argument you're passing to .find() is a javascript object. In your case it looks like, `{ CurrentLoc: {}, field1: 'No', field2: 'Yes' }`. To build this dynamically with the value of cat, you'd have something like
`var toFind = { 
    CurrentLoc: {  },
    field1: 'No'
};
toFind[cat] = 'Yes';
`

and finally pass query to your .find() call

`var query = db.collection('User').find(toFind);
`

Comment: This is perfect works great! thanks so much!

Comment: Always glad to help.