# Dynamic MongoDB query with $gte and $lte?

Tags: mongodb

This is my basic Timesheet object query:

```
return TimeSheet.find({
    submitDate : { '$gte': util.minDate(params.startDate), '$lte': util.maxDate(params.endDate)},
    submitted: true,
    user: params.userId
}, callBack(res)).populate('user timeEntries');
```

However, I'd like to search on `submitDate` or `workDate` based on a front end filter without wrapping this and another query in an if statement based on the passed in value. I'd like to do the `$gte` and `$lte` on a field defined by a variable.

I've looked at some other answers on here, such as [this one here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039018/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-field-name-in-mongodb-native-findone?rq=1) but it seems to be a little simple for what I'm trying to do.

What's the proper syntax here? I've tried looking through MongoDB documentation but I can't seem to get it. Is this possible?

This is what I've tried thus far.

```
var query = {};


query['submitDate'] = [];
query['submitDate']['$gte'] = util.minDate(params.startDate);
query['submitDate']['$lte'] = util.maxDate(params.endDate);
```

Comment: When putting together a dynamic query like this, you can easily check whether it is correct or not by debugging through and examining the state of the _query_ variable. It should, if your buildup is correct, have a structure exactly like the one in your first code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be very similar to the reference you've cited:

```
var dateFilterToUse = /*logic to populate this varibale with "submitDate" or "workDate" based on your front end filter*/;
var findJSON = {
    submitted: true,
    user: params.userId
};
findJSON[dateFilterToUse]= { '$gte': util.minDate(params.startDate), '$lte': util.maxDate(params.endDate)};

return TimeSheet.find(findJSON, callBack(res)).populate('user timeEntries');
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. I think I was over complicating things hah.