# How can I use $each and $position while using $push with a variable field name?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This code is working for me:

```
var currentUser = Meteor.userId()
var json = {}
json[currentUser] = {score: -1, created: new Date()}
Words.update({_id: word._id}, {
        $push: json
    }
)
```

But I would like to put new array items at the zero position.

How can I modify this code to use $each and $position?

Comment: In above query in which field you are pushing json, as you haven't mentioned field name.

Comment: The field name becomes something like 'KxXJYDLvCvjk9nLwo'. Because currentUser is something like 'KxXJYDLvCvjk9nLwo'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Meteor, but in plain javascript you need to mention field name after $push, and you will push any variable at first place by below query.

```
 Words.update({_id: word._id}, {
            $push: {field_name: {
               $each: [ json ],
               $position: 0
            }}
        }
    )
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting "field_name" to be variable.

Comment: there is no dynamic variable in field name in mongodb, you need to use static field name

Comment: But using my original code it does create a variable field name.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
    var currentUser = Meteor.userId()
    var json = {score: -1, created: new Date()}
    Words.update({_id: word._id}, {
            $push: {
                [currentUser]: {
                    $each: [json],
                    $position: 0
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Special thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375036/538034