# Mongodb: add field to matching child element

Tags: mongodb

I have this Mongodb document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a22e86c64b6d80e384f504a"),
    "ruc" : "20455412215",
    "razon_social" : "EMPRESA A",
    "representantes" : [ 
        {
            "tipo_representante" : "accionista",
            "dni_representante" : "42541773",
            "nombres_representante" : "MARIO PEREZ"
        },
        {
            "tipo_representante" : "accionista",
            "dni_representante" : "42541774",
            "nombres_representante" : "ROBERTO GOMEZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add this field: **"imagenDNI": "uploads\file-1512427693006.png"** to the child that matches **"dni_representante":"42541774"**, so this would be the result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a22e86c64b6d80e384f504a"),
    "ruc" : "20455412215",
    "razon_social" : "EMPRESA A",
    "representantes" : [ 
        {
            "tipo_representante" : "accionista",
            "dni_representante" : "42541773",
            "nombres_representante" : "MARIO PEREZ"
        },
        {
            "tipo_representante" : "accionista",
            "dni_representante" : "42541774",
            "nombres_representante" : "ROBERTO GOMEZ",
            "imagenDNI": "uploads\file-1512427693006.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

I try this code

```
db.getCollection('empresas')
    .update({ "representantes.dni_representante" : "42541773" }
        , {$set: {"representantes.$": { "imagenDNI": 'uploads\file-1512427693006.png' }}})
```

But instead of adding the field, it replaces the whole child fields, showing this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a22e86c64b6d80e384f504a"),
    "ruc" : "20455412215",
    "razon_social" : "EMPRESA A",
    "representantes" : [ 
        {
            "tipo_representante" : "accionista",
            "dni_representante" : "42541773",
            "nombres_representante" : "MARIO PEREZ"
        },
        {
            "imagenDNI": "uploads\file-1512427693006.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I add the field instead of replacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up.*S*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) you should use

```
db.collection.update( { <query selector> },
                      { <update operator>: { "array.$.field" : value } })
```

So you may try:

```
db.getCollection('empresas')
.update({ "representantes.dni_representante" : "42541773" }
    , {$set: {"representantes.$.imagenDNI": 'uploads\file-1512427693006.png' }})
```

Comment: In case of imagenDNI is a variable contain field name. You may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039018/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-field-name-in-mongodb-native-findone

Comment: You are the best! Thank you! Exactly what I needed. I was gonna do the search myself but you've just saved me time.