# MongoDB – How do I return documents with <field_value> as <field_key>?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

After some research I've seen ways to go around this through mongoDB's $mapReduce feature, however I haven't managed to get it working.. Here's what I'm dealing with:

```
[
  {
    _id: '1',
    device_id: 'ML39A-341D4-UI041',
    date: '2018-03-28T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    _id: '2',
    device_id: 'ML39A-341D4-UI041',
    date: '2018-03-29T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    _id: '3',
    device_id: 'D4YK2-R2D20-KYPI9'
    date: '2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z'
  }
]
```

The expected result after aggregation should look like this:

```
[
  {
    'ML39A-341D4-UI041': [
      '2018-03-28T00:00:00.000Z',
      '2018-03-29T00:00:00.000Z'
    ]
  },
  {
    'D4YK2-R2D20-KYPI9': [
      '2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z'
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the aggregation framework using a **`$group`** to group documents by `device_id`, followed by a **`arrayToObject`** to get a value as key:

the query looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$device_id",
    "dt": {
      "$push": "$date"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [{
            "k": "$_id",
            "v": "$dt"
          }]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

results:

```
[
  {
    "D4YK2-R2D20-KYPI9": [
      "2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    ]
  },
  {
    "ML39A-341D4-UI041": [
      "2018-03-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2018-03-29T00:00:00.000Z"
    ]
  }
]
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/t9AjMA0nXCn](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t9AjMA0nXCn)

Comment: You are a wizard!! Thank you so much