# How can I pass a variable into a mongoid query on a hash field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Class `Business` has a hash field `hours` that looks like this:

```
{
  monday: 
    {
      open_hour: 9,
      open_min: 0,
      close_hour: 17,
      close_min: 45
    }
  tuesday: 
  ...
}
```

My desired query looks like this:

```
Business.where(:'hours.monday.close_hour'.lt => 23)
```

which is functional in and of itself.. However, I'd like to pass `monday` in as a variable `day`, ie.

```
Business.where(:'hours.[day].close_hour'.lt => 23)
```

Is there a good way to do this? Note that this is part of a larger query chain that must return a `Mongoid::Criteria` object.

Comment: Have you tried `:"hours.[#{day}].close_hour"`? It's a shortcut for `"hours.[#{day}].close_hour".to_sym`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039018/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-field-name-in-mongodb-native-findone

We actually used the methodology found in the above link.  Built a query hash and then inserted. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately we came up with this:

`query = { :"hours.#{day}.close_hour" => { '$lt' => 23 } }
Business.where(query)`

Source: [How to use a variable as a field name in mongodb-native findOne()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039018/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-field-name-in-mongodb-native-findone)

Thanks!

Edit: I'd like to point out that user 'mu is too short' recognised that it can just as easily be written like this:

`:"hours.#{day}.close_hour".lt => 23`

which is much closer to our original intent.

Comment: `:"hours.#{day}.close_hour"` is still a Symbol so `:"hours.#{day}.close_hour".lt => 23` would still work. As would `:"hours.#{day}.close_hour" => { :$lt => 23 }` or `"hours.#{day}.close_hour" => { '$lt' => 23 }` or ...

Comment: Right you are! I think we accidentally used single quotes when that wasn't working for us.. I actually still like formatting and declaring the queries as variables at the top of the method and calling them as needed because there are quite a few queries.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Changed my mind.. your syntax is much better. really appreciate it.

Comment: The downside of using `:symbol.op` is that it can hide that you're really just building a hash with `:symbol` as a key. I remember running into that a few times when trying to build MongoDB queries piece by piece.