# How does 'fuzzy' work in MongoDB's $searchBeta stage of aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm not quite understanding how fuzzy works in the $searchBeta stage of aggregation. I'm not getting the desired result that I want when I'm trying to implement full-text search on my backend. Full text search for MongoDB was released last year (2019), so there really aren't many tutorials and/or references to go by besides the documentation. I've read the documentation, but I'm still confused, so I would like some clarification.

Let's say I have these 5 documents in my db:

```
{
    "name": "Lightning Bolt",
    "set_name": "Masters 25"
},
{
    "name": "Snapcaster Mage",
    "set_name": "Modern Masters 2017"
},
{
    "name": "Verdant Catacombs",
    "set_name": "Modern Masters 2017"
},
{
    "name": "Chain Lightning",
    "set_name": "Battlebond"
},
{
    "name": "Battle of Wits",
    "set_name": "Magic 2013"
}
```

And this is my aggregation in MongoDB Compass:

```
db.cards.aggregate([
    {
        $searchBeta: {
            search: { //search has been deprecated, but it works in MongoDB Compass; replace with 'text'
                query: 'lightn',
                path: ["name", "set_name"],
                fuzzy: { 
                    maxEdits: 1, 
                    prefixLength: 2, 
                    maxExpansion: 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

What I'm expecting my result to be:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Lightning Bolt", //lightn is in 'Lightning'
        "set_name": "Masters 25"
    },
    {
        "name": "Chain Lightning", //lightn is in 'Lightning'
        "set_name": "Battlebond"
    }
]
```

What I actually get:

```
[] //empty array
```

I don't really understand why my result is empty, so it would be much appreciated if someone explained what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening: 
db.cards.aggregate... is looking for documents in the "name" and "set_name" fields for words that have a max edit of one character variation from the "lightn" query. The documents that are in the cards collection contain edits that are greater than 2, and therefor your expected result is an empty array. "Fuzzy is used to find strings which are similar to the search term or terms"; used with maxEdits and prefixLength.

Have you tried the [term operator with the wildcard option](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/term/)? I think the below aggregation would get you the results you were actually expecting.

```
e.g.            
    db.cards.aggregate([
        {$searchBeta: 
            {"term": 
                {"path": 
                     ["name","set_name"],
                      "query": "l*h*",
                      "wildcard":true}
          }}]).pretty()
```

Comment: thanks for answering. While the wildcard option does work, I had forgot to mention that I'm using the full-text search for my full-stack app. How would I query for something dynamically? For example, instead of a hardcode query string like "l*h*", how would I query a javascript variable that is equal to "lightn"? This variable changes as the user types.

Comment: I think (don't quote me) for your use case you would need to set the key of the query object dynamically by using []. checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039018/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-field-name-in-mongodb-native-findone for a similar topic

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an index to use with your search query.
The index is basically the analyzer that your query will use to process your results regarding if you want to a full match of the text, or you want a partial match etc.
You can read more about Analyzers from [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/analyzers/)

In your case, an index based on STANDARD analyzer will help.
After you create your index your code, modified below, will work:

```
db.cards.aggregate([
    {
        $search:{
            text: { //search has been deprecated, but it works in MongoDB Compass; replace with 'text'
                index: 'index_name_for_analyzer (STANDARD in your case)'
                query: 'lightn',
                path: ["name"] //since you only want to search in one field
                fuzzy: { 
                    maxEdits: 1, 
                    prefixLength: 2, 
                    maxExpansion: 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```